# Mod_Security Roadblocks, Hosting EE

Tags: safecracker, security, server, hosting

I am experiencing recurring issues related to Mod_Security with EE on my current host, HostGator. I have seen HostGator suggested as a good host for EE projects in several articles and my work already has a production server there so that's what I've been using, however a little while back I experienced an issue with JS libraries not loading in the admin control panel which turned out to be a Mod_Security issue, and HostGator does not have any Mod_Security settings in their Cpanel, so I had to have a back and forth with their support team which took several days to resolve.

I am now getting another Mod_Security message when I try to use the EE Chanel Form tags.

To test the feature I made this simple form:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="order_reports"}
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

And when I submit I get this:

> Not Acceptable!
>   An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

I do not want to have to contact support for my host every time I need to run a form post action, or anything else for that matter.

Since HostGator no longer seems viable due to their lack of Mod_Security controls, I would like to know from some people here who have experience with the more complex features of EE what hosts they use or would suggest. I will need to switch from HostGator and I am not in a position to troubleshoot a bunch of different hosts until I find one that doesn't have a problem with EE.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is still to open a support ticket with HostGator and asking them to 'whitelist' those mod_sec rules that are causing the problem. As EE5 isn't as common as say WordPress, most hosting providers therefore don't have the relevant rules whitelisted as they don't have clients that have run into the issue (yet).

If you ask them nicely they might be able to do this for your server/all domains you want to use EE5 with.

Most shared hosts will have the same issue unless they already have clients running EE sites and have whitelisted the rules server wide.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I contacted them yesterday, and they said they'd adjust the whitelist and send me an email. Didn't hear back this morning so I contacted them again and they said the same thing, haha. Oh well! The life of a web dev I guess.